# На сколько тяжёл в c# вызов лямбды, которая была получена через рефлесию?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Есть такой код.

```
 string listPropertyName = "List";  
 Action<TMain,TSub> _push = (main, sub) => 
    ((List<TSub>)(typeof(TMain).GetProperty(listPropertyName).GetValue(main))).Add(sub);
```

Этот код создаём экшен, который добавляет второй аргумент в свойство (в коллекцию) первого аргумента с именем listPropertyName. Но это не суть.

Вопрос в том, как часто тут будут работать тяжёлые механизмы рефлексии: только при создание, или каждый раз при вызове? И если всё плохо, то как оптимизировать?

Comment: Тут дело не в лямбде. Сама по себе лямбда - это синтаксический сахарок. А вот рефлексия, да, нагружает малеха.

Comment: @Bulson , вопрос в том, как часто она будет это делать, если один раз при создание, то всё ок.

Comment: поздравляю, вы ответили на свой вопрос самостоятельно.

Comment: @Bulson, ну так я ещё не понял, когда вся эта рефлексия будет ворочаться.

Comment: Судя по тому, что вы присваиваете значение делегату, то вызов рефлексии будет происходить всякий раз, когда вы будете вызывать этот делегат на выполнение.

Comment: @Bulson, ну да, логично, нет случайно предложений по оптимизации?

Comment: Хм, я не вижу всей картины. Подобраться к `TMain` кроме как через рефлексию разве нельзя? Сделать так, чтоб под TMain фигурировал тип реализующий интерфейс в кот. было бы свойство типа `List<Tsub>`. Короче через интерфейсы можно попробовать уйти от рефлексии, если, конечно, вы не подгружаете типы динамически из других `dll`.

Comment: Можно попробовать запомнить вот эту часть: `((List<TSub>)(typeof(TMain).GetProperty(listPropertyName).GetValue(main)))` и уже к запомненому результату `List<TSub>` применять `Add`, таким образом рефлексия вызывается один раз, а метод `Add` сколько угодно.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще рефлексия? Расскажите, какую задачу вы решаете и почему её нельзя решить без рефлексии.